# How to make execution plans as most accurate as possible

Tags: mysql

every night I make a dump of my PROD environment (mysql 8.0.23) to import it in my TEST environment. The hardware and the mysql config is the same on both systems

I noticed that some query (executed just after the dump, when the 2 databases are still aligned) behave in a different way on the 2 systems, with different execution plans and, of course, different performances

My guess is that the TEST environment performs better because every table is created from scratch, so the stats for tables and indexes are more accurate, while PROD is loaded with tons of inserts, updates, deletes during the day.

Is there any way to make PROD behave the same way?

I tryed to run OPTIMIZE and ANALYZE on every table (most of them are InnoDB), but the execution plans are still different

Thanks

Comment: Drop tables and reimport them again could help.

Comment: Notwitstanding the answer below, this is probably a better fit on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

- The fresh load on TEST needs to do more I/O because the "cache" is initially empty.  (Cf InnoDB's buffer_pool.)  I would expect that TEST might be up to 10 *times* as slow.  Run the same query again to see it speed up.
- `EXPLAIN` makes estimates; it is usually inconsistent.  Don't worry about that.
- If PROD is quite busy, but TEST is just running a single query, PROD could be slower.  This is due to the other stuff that is going on.
- `OPTIMIZE` is essentially never needed for InnoDB; don't waste time on it.
- `ANALYZE` will sometimes convince `EXPLAIN` to provide a different query plan.  This does not prove much.
- Drop and reimport is unlikely to resolve anything.

Show us one example of a notable difference.  We are more likely to spot something when given a specific example.  Provide

- The query
- EXPLAIN SELECT -- on both servers
- Timing for the queries
- SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table(s) involved in the query.